# Javascript using onload twice in html file and external script file

Tags: javascript, onload

I have an external JS file that I load into my HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/busy.js"></script>
```

The script file itself looks like this:

```
window.onload = setupFunc;

     function setupFunc() {
       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = clickFunc;
       hideBusysign();
         Wicket.Ajax.registerPreCallHandler(showBusysign);
         Wicket.Ajax.registerPostCallHandler(hideBusysign);
         Wicket.Ajax.registerFailureHandler(hideBusysign);
     }

     function hideBusysign() {
       document.getElementById('busy').style.display ='none';
     }

     function showBusysign() {
       document.getElementById('busy').style.display ='block';
     }

     function clickFunc(eventData) {
       var clickedElement = (window.event) ? event.srcElement : eventData.target;
       if (clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'BUTTON' || clickedElement.type.toUpperCase() == 'SUBMIT') {
         showBusysign();
       }
     }
```

Basically, it shows a little busy indicator within my website.

I also have an onload function in my body tag, this is new and helps me focus on the username text field when the page loads.

```
<body lang="de" class="fade-in one" onLoad="document.forms.login.username.focus();">
```

However, since I added this last functionality, the busy indicator stopped working because it also uses the onload function. What can I do to make it work again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not the most elegant way .. but it will work

```
<body lang="de" class="fade-in one" onLoad="document.forms.login.username.focus();setupFunc();">
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove your body onload tag and put:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    document.forms.login.username.focus();
    setupFunc();
};
</script>
```

After your external Javascript (make sure it's still in the `<head>` tag). That should change window.onLoad to your custom function, which does what you need and then calls setupFunc.

Comment: won't work as long as there is a onload attribute in the body tag :)

Comment: There's no need for an onload tag any more, that function does both things. Updated to make it clear

Comment: i know that there is no need for the body onload anymore :) but without your update, I bet he would have left it there.. in fact your solution is the same as mine.. but with more characters ;)

Comment: Thanks for your solution as well. Unfortunately I can only pick one answer.. +1